# firefox isn't showing my image link as a complete link

Tags: html, css, firefox

So I have an image that is between 2 anchor tags.  the css for the image is..

```
#howDoesItWork {
position: absolute;
height: 31px;
width: 154px;
    border-style: none;
top: 3px;
left: 20px;
}
```

the right 20 px of the image isn't being noticed as a link in firefox.  It works fine in IE.  I tried changing it to padding left: 20px and margin-left: 20px.  It still shows that last 20px as not being part of the link.  It works fine I take the positioning away completely though.

```
<a id="howDoesItWork" href="">
<img src="images/howDoesItWork.jpg" alt=""/>
</a>
```

FIXED: I set the z-index to 2.  Apparent the menu right next to it was overlapping onto the howDoesItWork imaage.

Comment: What's your HTML? I'm not entirely sure what `"an image that is between 2 anchor tags"` means.

Answer (score 2):

When you absolute position the image the link doesn't use the image to base its width on.

Because you've set a left: 20px it will stick over the range of the link.

So you need to extend the coverage of the link.  Without knowing anything else about your document (ie. columns, what you are trying to do) my best guess is:

```
a #howDoesItWork { padding-right: 20px; }
```

If that doesn't do it... just show us more information.

#### UPDATE

With the new html info it should be:

```
#howDoesItWork { padding-right: 20px; }
```

Comment: yea that didn't do it and i even changed the is from the anchor tag to the img tag

Comment: I need to see the exact page that you are working on. When I try to mock this up, it is working correctly.  I have a feeling that it either the image size or some other style I don't know about.  Full code on jsFiddle or something equivalent?

Comment: FIXED: I set the z-index to 2.  Apparent the menu right next to it was overlapping onto the howDoesItWork imaage.